# cannot import name 'delayed' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda

How should the `cannot import name 'delayed' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes` be solved? I have already updated sklearn and upgraded conda as well.

```
~\.conda\envs\base2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in <module>
         30 from ..utils._mask import _get_mask
         31 from ..utils.validation import _deprecate_positional_args
    ---> 32 from ..utils.fixes import delayed
         33 from ..utils.fixes import sp_version, parse_version
         34 
    
    ImportError: cannot import name 'delayed' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes'`
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After the installation via `pip install delayed` and then restarting the kernel, the problem was solved.

Comment: I had this issue using conda, and restarting the kernel helped as well.

Comment: Even after this if you don't restart the kernel it will continue showing the above error.  This solution + restart kernel works.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn
conda install nb_conda # to grant to select conda environments as core of jupyter notebook
```

[See more at this link.](http://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/install.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Restarting the kernel solved the issue for me.**

*If you check your log, somehow you upgraded some modules, and kernels need to be restarted sometimes, to get the changes reflected in the system.*